# How to dynamically change var value on click?

Tags: javascript, html

Actually in my site i have a table with a lot of download link for each version so i would be able to change the file version that the user is trying to download.

Like here is one of items from my table:

```
<tr>
    <td> App</td>
    <td id="0.9.0">0.9.0</td>
    <td>02/01/2019</td>
    <td><a href="#" aria-disabled="true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" onclick="version = document.getElementById("0.9.0").innerText; alert.version;>Download</a></td>
</tr>
```

After i press download i'd open the bootstrap modal in which i should insert the right password and then i the user press download it should download the right file version.

Here is my method used in onClick of the modal button:

```
<script>
    var input = document.getElementById("Key");
    var btn = document.getElementById("download");
    var version;

    btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (input.value == "1234") {
            window.location = '/App/App_0.9.0.apk'; (this 0.9.0 should be dynamic)
            $("#exampleModalCenter").modal('hide')
        }
    });
</script>
```

UPDATE AFTER (Oen44 answer):

I've changed the a tag to this:

```
<tr>
    <td>App</td>
    <td>0.9.0</td>
    <td>02/01/2019</td>
    <td><a href="#" aria-disabled="true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" data-version="0.9.0" onclick="version = this.getAttribute('data-version');">Download</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>App</td>
    <td>0.2.3</td>
    <td>02/01/2019</td>
    <td><a href="#" aria-disabled="true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" data-version="0.2.3" onclick="version = this.getAttribute('data-version');">Download</a></td>
</tr>
```

While the script is still the same :

```
var input = document.getElementById("Key");
var btn = document.getElementById("download");
let version;

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (input.value == "1234") {
        window.location = '/App/App_${version}.apk';
        $("#exampleModalCenter").modal('hide')
    }
});
```

But when i'm trying to download the file but nothing is heppening

Comment: Can you use dots as id? what will prevent `#0.9.0` to be interpolated as an element with  `id 0 and with class 9 and class 0`

Comment: @AlonEitan so how could i do as i could have 30 items in the table, i have to put different id for each <td> version with not dotted names?

Comment: `id="0-9-0"` IMO

Comment: But that is not efficient.

Comment: @Oen44 yeah i've noticed it..

Comment: What @Oen44 suggested in his comment to his answer is good. The idea of my comment was as a general rule to not use dots because I don't think it's valid, and even if it is, it's confusing

Comment: @AlonEitan Dots are valid and `getElementById` will work without problems. It's just weird looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to change

`<td id="0.9.0">0.9.0</td>` - don't use that format as id.

`<td id="app-version">0.9.0</td>` - way better

```
let version = document.getElementById('app-version').innerText;
window.location = `/App/App_${version}.apk`; // now with generate /App/App_0.9.0.apk
```

#### Edit

```
<a href="#" data-version="0.9.0" onclick="version = this.getAttribute('data-version');">Download</a>
```

#### Edit2

If you want to format string in JS using `${}` then string must be in ``` `` ```

```
`/App/RealcoApp_${version}.apk`
```

Comment: should i put "let version = document.getElementById('app-version').innerText;" in the onClick? Actually i have to change the id for each td or i doesnot? as i have a lot of td with the different versions

Comment: `id` must be unique. If you are using button then you can use `data` attribute on that button and set version number there.

Comment: actually i can't get how to pass the version to the variable... as the variable is initialized in the <script> but i would change it's value onClick.. I'm trying to add "onclick= version = "0.2.3";" to don't use a lot of id's but it's not working

Comment: actually i'm trying to use your answer but it's still having no effect.. i've updated my question

Comment: just solved by using ' /App/RealcoApp_' + version +'.apk' ' thank you :)